# Simplify the following expression containing trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I want to simplify the following expression:

$$\sqrt3\sin60^\circ - 3\cos60^\circ-\tan210^\circ$$

This is what I was able to figure out:

$$3\cos60^\circ = {\cos60^\circ}^{3} = 1$$

Therefore:

$$\sqrt3\sin60^\circ - 1-\tan210^\circ$$

I don't know how to simplify the expression anymore, but I know that ${\tan210^\circ} = {\sin210^\circ \over \cos210^\circ}$. Any hints?

Comment: Use the known values $\cos 60^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$ , $\sin 60^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ , $\tan 210^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: Thanks @ComplexPhi. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You can either plug the numbers in directly as mentioned in one of the comments, or note that
$$
\tan 210^\circ = \tan (180^\circ +30^\circ) = \tan 30^circ = \cot 60^\circ
= \frac{\cos 60^\circ}{\sin 60^\circ}
$$